# Where is the call to persistence in the domain driven design

Tags: c#, .net, persistence, domain-driven-design

I know there is a lot of similar information online and also on stackoverflow, but I'm still not sure where to put the logic of persistence into my project. I don't yet use any ORM, IoC and UnitOfWork concepts (too much new stuff for a beginner in the ddd world).

I see two options for my Order model:

1. Inside the Domain assembly there is an `Order` class and an `IOrderRepository` interface. `Order` class has a private instance of the `IOrderRepository` which is passed in the constructor. Order class has a public `Insert` method, which calls the `IOrderRepository.Insert` method. The actual implementetion of the repository is in `OrderRepository` class of the Infrastructure layer. The Service layer would contain an `OrderService` class which instantiates my model with the appropriate repository and then calls `Order.Insert()`. The bad: we have to inject an interface (or multiple instances) of the repository to the model class, persistence logic is inside the model. The good: sometimes something has to be done before or after the insert method is called and this could nicely fit into the `Insert` method of the `Order` class, for example raising domain events or whatever.
2. In the `Model` assembly there is only `Order` class. The Service layer creates new `Order` and new `OrderRepository` and executes `orderRepository.Insert(order)`.

Could you please explain which concept is better in simple words (explain like I'm Five).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your domain classes should be focused on business logic of domain only, and they should be persistent ignorant (i.e. persistence should be separated from business logic). Adding persistence-related operations violates Single Responsibility Principle. Also  dependency on repository makes your domain classes complex, instead of being simple POCO entities.

Let's think about this design from coding point. You have to provide repository instance to each `Order`, and then call `order.Insert()` for this order to pass itself to repository which you have injected into order. Sounds complicated. Much simpler will be use `repository.Save(order)`. Sometimes it's OK to have CRUD methods on class (see [Active Record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern). But this approach is good when you don't have complex domain model.

I think best place for persistence of your domain is application services (maybe you call this layer as *Service* layer). They load entities from repositories, perform operations (it could be simple operations on entities, or calls to domain services), and then state of domain gets saved.

Comment: Then you have seperate unit tests, one for Order class (just business logic) and one for OrderService class (with mock repositories)?

Comment: @sventevit exactly, one set of tests for business rules of your domain. Other set of tests for application logic

Comment: And what if you need some complex logic inside the model classes, which needs to call other repositories or infrastructure calls?

Comment: @sventevit you simply should not have such logic on domain classes :) Persisting or communicating with infrastructure layer is responsibility of application services